# Handlebars/Node changing date format

Tags: javascript, node.js, handlebars.js, metalsmith

While outputting a date field through Handlebars **to HTML on the server-side**, it's giving me a different format than what's visible in the API when debugging. I've tried using both double and triple braces for output. I need that pure UTC time.

**API DATA**

```
data: {
  date:
    html: "<time>Sun Apr 28 2019 19:00:00 GMT-0500 (CDT)</time>",
    json: {
      value: "2019-04-29T00:00:00.000Z"
    }
  },
  title: {
    html: "<h3>Blah blah</h3>",
    json: {...}
  }
}
```

**TEMPLATE** (Handlebars)

```
<div data-date="{{{ data.date.json.value }}}">
  {{ getTextField data 'title' }}
</div>
```

**EXPECTED OUTOUT**

```html
<div data-date="2019-04-29T00:00:00.000Z">
  <h3>Blah blah</h3>
</div>
```

**ACTUAL OUTPUT**

```html
<div data-date="Sun Apr 28 2019 19:00:00 GMT-0500 (CDT)">
  <h3>Blah blah</h3>
</div>
```

Comment: The date in the value is GMT +0000 your local is GMT -0500 so it is showing correctly.

Comment: This is server-side rendering.

Comment: it is rendering it exactly as you asked it to. I think you need to register a helper in handlebars to format the date.

Comment: It's not. It's converting the string "2019-04-29T00:00:00.000Z" into "Sun Apr 28 2019 19:00:00 GMT-0500 (CDT)" when outputting the field value to a template. How can I keep the UTC time value?

Comment: it's converting the date (not string) to a string format determine by your locale. I recommend you make a handlebars helper to display in UTC

Comment: This is API response data, a date object is never created. Are you saying when Node encounters this type of string value in an API response, it interprets that into a date object and outputs another format automatically when used... this date object outputs one way when the parent is console logged and another via templates?

Comment: Logging to the console might format it differently to handlebars. I haven't looked at the internals of either. I think you could see this by trying the `typeof` operator on it but if it is a string then handlebars is converting it to a date then formatting it as you see it.

Comment: None of this is in the console. This is the rendered HTML via Handlebars on the server-side.

Comment: So add some? or log it somewhere else maybe even to a file?

Comment: Your suggestion is to add another type of debug that will likely to change the value while outputting. This doesn't seem useful.

Comment: If the value is changing due to logging then something is seriously wrong. I suggested the extra logging to show you that the value hasn't changed. Javascript will format dates with local culture settings by default which is what you're seeing.